# Users who are not logged in can not view certain pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

So I am building an app in rails 4, and I have some conditions which determines what a user can see or not see on a page, for instance, if a user has created a project - they can see the edit / delete options for that project, while others can not. Here is that bit of code, which lives in the projects#show view:

```
    <!--  make sure only the creator can edit or add updates -->
    <% if current_user == @project.user || current_user.admin == true %>
        <ul>
          <li><%= button_to "Edit", edit_project_path(@project), method: :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %></li>
          <li><%= button_to "Add Update", new_project_update_path(:project_id => @project.id), method: :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %></li>
        </ul>
    <%end%>
```

The problem is that when a user is not logged in the page breaks because current_user = nil, and rails doesn't know what to do with that. What are some different approaches to resolving this? I would like to put something in the application controller (maybe) that will automatically assign guest user to everybody until they explicitly log in (without them having to sign in as a guest) as I would like people to be able to view certain pages without having to do anything at all. I have tried that, unsuccessfully. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if current_user is set first

```
<% if current_user && (current_user == @project.user || current_user.admin == true) %>
```

or more specifically

```
<% if !current_user.nil? && ( other conditions) %>
```

Comment: perfect! IDK why I couldn't seem to wrap mind around such a small thing today, lol. Thank you ;)

Comment: But don't... Use an authorisation gem (like cancancan) to remove the conditional calculations from your views.

Answer (score 0):

Putting conditional permissions checks into your views rapidly becomes a nightmare to maintain. Consider what happens when you decide you want to add another user type called "collaborator" who can view projects, but not edit them. You'll need to trawl every view in your app and find every link to projects and alter the conditional.

The you add another layer... Like you want to suspend a collaborator from some projects but not others... All those conditions are going into views (where they really have no business being).
*AND* they need to all be duplicated in the controllers too - just because users can't see links, doesn't mean they can't edit URLs and change form targets. So all your permissions need to be double-checked in the actions, and if trying to manually keep them in sync is a very brittle approach.

What you really want to do is what your question says... Just put a link if they can, and no link if they cannot.

This is exactly the syntax of the [cancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check that out!